# JIRA: How can I change the ID of a CustomField option?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to implement a CustomField that is periodically updated from an external data source (a remote REST-Api). Following some tutorials and by extending SelectCFType, I could get a simple Select-Box with a few values to work as intended.

My problem is that I need to update these values periodically:

I use the OptionManager's createOption(...) method to create the options for my Select-Box. When I do, I can set the option's value and sequence, but I can't set a custom ID. JIRA seems to insist on generating these IDs automatically, which means that every time I clear and update my options with the values I just fetched from remote, they get new ID's. In turn, all issues that already had an option set lose that selection, since the stored ID doesn't match any of the new ones.

This seems like something a lot of plugins would use, for one reason or another. Is it simply not possible to use my own ID's?

A shortened version of the code I use:

```
Options options = this.optionsManager.getOptions(fieldConfig);
if (options.isEmpty()) {

    ArrayList<JSONObject> projects = GetProjectList();

    for (int i = 0; i < projects.size(); i++) {
        Long id = projects.get(i).getLong("id");
        String identifier = projects.get(i).getString("name");
        this.optionsManager.createOption(fieldConfig, null, id, identifier);
    }

}
options = this.optionsManager.getOptions(fieldConfig);
```

To clear all options, I used `this.optionsManager.removeCustomFieldOptions(field)`.

I'm new to JIRA development, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the options of a select field from outside JIRA, you can try exactly the opposite: let JIRA fetch option values directly from your external database.

Search on the Atlassian Marketplace for terms "[database custom field](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=database%20custom%20field)" and you'll find free and not free plugins to create a custom field of such type. The custom field itself will query an external DB (via SQL/driver for example) and fetch the options on the fly.